# How do i calculate the maxima in a Polynomial between two roots.

Tags: polynomials

I'm writing a program that plots compaction curves for soil density tests.

I have very little math background and I'm using Extreme Optimization's Math Library to curve fit my data(linear least squares) and plotting it as either a 2nd or 3rd degree polynomial.  Finding max's in 2nd degree was straight forward but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get the max for 3rd degree polys.

Here's a sample of what i have:
$$P(x) =-0.00399730972447669x^3-0.270240772455719x^2+6.44622423832016x+91.4780393989453$$

And roots at $x_1 =-83.6183853039161$, $x_2 = -10.3725525112563$, $x_3 =26.3852752364245$

how do i find the max that lives between the $-10$ and the $26$?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (relative) maximum of a cubic polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ is attained at one of the roots of the derivative $3ax^2+2bx+c$. So, if you still remember how to solve the quadratic, just do it and see which root is in the required range.

Comment: 124.9! Thank you for your help.